# storing normalized data with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers, normalizr

I would like my reducers to populate a root object in the state, independently from the slice of state they operate on.

I have found many pages explaining how wonderful is normalizr, but no one is explaining where and how to store this normalized data.

Questions are:

1. am I trying to do something unusual and wrong?
2. how can I modify state in the root state object, since reducers only operate on a slice of the data.

so videos reducer:

```
const videos = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {  
    case 'LOAD_VIDEOS': {
      return ....
    }
  }
}
```

should populate not only `state.videos` (with a array of video id), but also `state.database.videos` (and other keys as well if video contains other entities) with normalized data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your reducer needs to work on more than a slice of state, give it the whole state.

If you're using `combineReducers()`, you can wrap it so you keep the advantages of combining reducers and you can still have a reducer that works on the full state:

```
function somePartOfState(state, action) {
  // ...
}
function otherPartOfState(state, action) {
  // ...
}
function fullState(state, action) {
  // ...
}

const combined = combineReducers({
  somePartOfState,
  otherPartOfState
});

export function rootReducer(state, action) {
  // call the combined reducers, 
  // then pass the resulting state to the fullState reducer
  return fullState(combined(state, action), action);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Actually, I don't have special requirements, just a plain application, so I was wondering why this approach is not advertised on any blog, documentation or tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the [official documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) starts with a plain function before moving to combined reducers and explains that combineReducers() is just a helper: "All combineReducers() does is generate a function that calls your reducers with the slices of state selected according to their keys, and combining their results into a single object again. It’s not magic."